# How to stop overwriting on the same file in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I want to save file seperately. I've used "Files.writeAsBytes(pdf.save())", But the problem is, it overwrites in the same file.

```
  savePDFfile(context) async {
    final String dir = (await getExternalStorageDirectory()).path;
    final String path = '$dir/pdf.pdf';
    final file = File(path);
    await file.exists()? file.delete():
    file.writeAsBytes(pdf.save());
    print("file saved");
    mat.Navigator.of(context)
        .push(mat.MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => PdfViewerPage(path: path)));
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the file path each time you save the pdf. For example by adding timestamp to the path -

```
final String path = '$dir/pdf${DateTime.now().toIso8601String())}.pdf';
```